# Трассировка стека исключений в Java

Tags: java, исключения

Метод `fillInStackTrace()`, реализованный в классе `Throwable` позволяет получить объект типа `Throwable`, с сохранением трассировки стека вызывающего объекта в только что созданном объекте.
Причина моего вопроса в следующем:

```
class one {
    static Throwable w_exc(){
        ArithmeticException ar_exc = new ArithmeticException();
        Throwable ar_exc_1 = ar_exc.fillInStackTrace();
        return ar_exc_1;}
    public static void main(String[] argc){
        Throwable exc_1 = w_exc();
        StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = exc_1.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement element : stacktrace){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
        System.out.println(exc_1.toClass());
    }
}
```

При выполнении получим:

```
one.w_exc(one.java:4)
one.main(one.java:7)
```

Но если перенести вызов метода `fillInStackTrace()` в метод `main()`:

```
class one {
    static Throwable w_exc(){
        ArithmeticException ar_exc = new ArithmeticException();
        return ar_exc;}
    public static void main(String[] argc){
        Throwable exc_1 = (w_exc()).fillInStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = exc_1.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement element : stacktrace){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

мы получим

```
one.main(one.java:6)
```

т.е. из стека потеряли методы, которые вызывались до этого, хотя в первом варианте сохранились. Так вот, **почему в первом внутренние методы сохранились, хотя при возврате объекта из метода они должны были быть вытолкнуты из стека и в обеих случаях возвращается объект одного и того же класса?** 
Вопрос может быть несколько простой, но все равно не смог понять.
upd. поднимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace()) `fillInStackTrace()` записывает в объект `Throwable` текущее состояние стека. Если использовать `getStackTrace()`, результат будет такой же, как в первом случае.

```
public static void main(String[] argc) {
    Throwable result = w_exc();
    // Throwable exc_1 = result.fillInStackTrace();
    // System.out.println(exc_1==result);
    for (StackTraceElement element: result.getStackTrace()) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, если раскомментировать строку с `fillInStackTrace()`, `StackTrace` в `result` будет изменён, нового объекта `Throwable` не создаётся.